# Get HornetQServerControl via core

Tags: hornetq

is it possible to get access to a HornetQServerControl via the HornetQ core API?
I read the [management](http://docs.jboss.org/hornetq/2.2.5.Final/user-manual/en/html/management.html#d0e6663) chapter from the documentation, but still have no idea how to get access. The only example I found in the sources uses JMX.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an example to access HornetQ managememet API with JMS

https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/blob/master/examples/jms/management/src/main/java/org/hornetq/jms/example/ManagementExample.java

Using HornetQ core API is similar.

You can also read the test https://github.com/hornetq/hornetq/blob/master/tests/integration-tests/src/test/java/org/hornetq/tests/integration/management/HornetQServerControlUsingCoreTest.java.